# How to implement pinch gestures in iCarousel for zooming in and zooming out

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, icarousel, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have implemented a gallery application by using `iCarousel`.Now I need to include pinch gestures to `zoom in or zoom out each image`.I added scroll view and tried the delegate methods.But no success. 
please help me with this.

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)indexs reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    imgview = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    UIImage * img = [items objectAtIndex:indexs];

    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320.0f,568)];

    ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page.png"];

    imgView.image= img ;
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
     self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.scrollView .frame = CGRectMake(18,10, 282, 568);
self.scrollView.delegate =self;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height);
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = MAXIMUM_SCALE;
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = MINIMUM_SCALE;
self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = NO;
[view addSubview:self.scrollView];
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[self.scrollView addSubview:imgView];




    view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    view.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
    view.layer.borderWidth=1;
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;


    return view;

}
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return imgView;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale
{

}
```

I have tried something like this.

And I tried adding pinch gestures to imgView also.

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried so far

Comment: Turns out all I needed to do was turn clipsToBounds off for the scrollView instances inside the carousel.

Comment: I have added some code to my question @AdamRichardson .Could you please have a look..

Comment: @Moseph Could you please elaborate on what you commented here.Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: select your scrollview & clips to bounds property off.

Comment: & one more hint set maxzoom & minzoom in scrollview

Comment: Thanks for your reply .But its not working for me :( @Moseph

Comment: Here should I set self.scrollview.delegate = self; Its not going to the delegate methods when I try to zoom

Comment: I think since scrollview is added as a subview of another subview,its delegate methods are not getting called.Could you please help me out with this.. :(